# How to use enum in Query when passed as variable

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, hibernate, jpa

I have this `Entity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
class Project(
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_owner_id")
    val projectOwner: ProjectOwner,
    @Column(name = "created", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    val created: ZonedDateTime,
    @Column(name = "valid_until", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    val validUntil: ZonedDateTime,
    @Column(name = "valid_from", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
    val validFrom: ZonedDateTime?,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column val type: ProjectType,
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long = 0
}
```

And this query in the corresponding `JPA repository`

```
@Query("""
    SELECT p FROM project p
    WHERE p.id = :projectId AND
    p.created <= :createDate AND
    p.type = :type
    """)
fun findProject(
    projectId: Long,
    type: ProjectType,
    createDate: ZonedDateTime,
): Project?


@EnumNaming(EnumNamingStrategies.CamelCaseStrategy::class)
enum class ProjectType {
    common,
    local,
    global,
}
```

If I try to use the function `findProject()` like this

```
ProjectRepository.findProject(1, ProjectType.local, ZonedDateTime.now())
```

I get

> ERROR: operator does not exist: type = character varying
> Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

So this `p.type = :type`, or better `:type` is interpreted as `character varying`.
So, I try as suggested and type cast (using a `native query` because I am not sure how to do this in the DSL)

```
@Query("""
    SELECT * FROM project p
    WHERE p.id = :projectId AND
    p.created <= :createDate AND
    p.type = CAST(:type as project_type)
    """, nativeQuery = true)
fun findProject(
    projectId: Long,
    type: ProjectType,
    createDate: ZonedDateTime,
): Project?
```

But, this gives me

> ERROR: cannot cast type smallint to type

So, it is using the `smallint` value of the `enum ProjectType`.

How to use a enum in a JPA `@Query` when it gets passed as a variable through a function?

Comment: Did you try to add @param to signature?
@Param("type") type: ProjectType,

Comment: @Feelfree I get the same errro `ERROR: operator does not exist: type = character varying`

Comment: Can you please show the Project entity?

Comment: @Feelfree I added the entity